# wxSound. Undefined reference to PlaySoundW@12

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, codeblocks, windows-7-x64

I try to use wxSound to play sound, but when I try to compile and linking all project. I have this error:

***C:\wxWidgets-3.0.2\build\msw/../../include/wx/msw/winundef.h:171: undefined reference to `PlaySoundW@12'***

I Google it and got the answer about adding option -lwinmm to the linker. But it doesn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you compiling and linking exactly? Have you tried building the `sound` sample that comes with wxWidgets?

This function is definitely in `winmm.lib` and wxWidgets makefiles already link with it. If they work and your code doesn't, chances are that you simply didn't add `-lwinmm` option in the correct place.

Comment: Sound example compiled successfuly. I have no idea what is wrong with my project config, here the screenshot - https://yadi.sk/i/9q9ON1aMfNppN and here is buildlog - http://pastebin.com/jhnsNNXt

Comment: As usual with static libraries, `-lwinmm` must come *after* the library using it, not before, as in your build log.